# How to validate date as characters are entered in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is an input where the user must enter a date in the format dd.mm.yyyy., And I need to check that he does not write letters and other unnecessary characters. The Internet is full of examples for a ready-made date, in my case it is necessary to check as you enter. For example, the user pressed the key 2 - it appeared in the input, pressed z - nothing changed in the input. Pressed 3 - ok, pressed / - nothing has changed. I tried to write a regular expression,

```
((0[1-9]{0,1})|([1-2][0-9]{0,1})|(3[0-1]{0,1}))\.{ 0.1}
```

but I can't figure out how to check the data after the dot. Need your advice.

Here is a small [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-burnell-yo9z4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What does "non-singular expression" mean?

Comment: regular expression, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just updated you tags on question, as your linked example was using React, and how you do this in plain JS would be slightly different.

Rather than regEx, a slightly easier option might be to use lookups, you could then check what valid chars are available at each char position.

Below is an example.
ps. It won't catch everything, eg. 31 days in Feb, & 29/28 for leap years etc.  So ideally you should check again after date fully entered.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const anynum = '01234567890';
const num01 = '01';
const num31 = '0123';
const dot = '.';

const posValid = [
  num31,    //3
  anynum,   //1
  dot,      //.
  num01,    //1
  anynum,   //2
  dot,      //.
  anynum,   //2
  anynum,   //0
  anynum,   //2
  anynum    //2
]

function partsValid(s) {
  if (s.length > posValid.length) return false;
  //simple num check at pos
  for (let l = 0; l < s.length; l += 1) {
    const c = s[l];
    if (!posValid[l].includes(c)) return false;
  }
  //check day
  if (s.length > 1) {
    const day = parseInt(s.slice(0, 2), 10);
    if (!(day >= 1 && day <= 31)) return false;
  }
  //check month
  if (s.length > 4) {
    const month = parseInt(s.slice(3, 5), 10);
    if (!(month >= 1 && month <= 12)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}


function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onchange = (e) => {
    const nv = e.target.value;
    if (partsValid(nv)) setValue(nv);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={onchange} value={value} placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: The idea is interesting. But 00.00.0000 is also a valid date.

Comment: @АлександрКос  You can certainly put extra checks in, but I'm not going to implement every single possible incorrect as you type date checks.  But I've added a simple  day / month check to my snippet, you could expand on this to do even more fine grained control.  eg.  Only allow certain months if day 31 is selected etc, all this is possible.